Simple MOSFET LED switch - interference when components are placed close together
A motorcycle daytime light controller outputs 100Hz standard PWM waveform to dim a power LED module. The output waveform is for dimming control only, so a switch is needed to handle the LED current (2.4A)
The waveform is negative going, so we have designed a really simple circuit to invert the waveform and switch a N-chan MOSFET, as N-chan has nice low S-D impedance.
Built it on solderless breadboard and it works perfectly. Transfer it to stripboard and you get an irregular low frequency flickering of the LED - at approximately 10 to 15Hz. Rebuilt the circuit on the breadboard with the components physically close together, as they are on the stripboard and it flickers. Move the components say 5cm apart on the breadboard and it works perfectly again.
This has got me somewhat baffled, it's like there is RF flying around but it's only operating at 100Hz. Tried various small de-coupling caps, no effect.
Any ideas would be much appreciated.
Transistor is 2N2222, NMOS is IRFB3206PBF


The NMOS in your schematic is upside down. Where's the PWM signal coming from? What's the frequency and what's the amplitude?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes, sorry I knocked up the diagram online. In the actual circuit it's the correct way round.
The PWM signal is coming from a light controller - a PWM dimmer basically. Amplitude is 12v. So when it's at +12 the LED is off, when it's at 0v the LED it on. Frequency is 100Hz

So the specific problem is that while it works perfectly on a breadboard, when you transfer it to a stripboard and the components are close together, we see erratic flickering of the LED. This also happens if the components are placed close together on the breadboard.
Obviously the project has to go to stripboard and finally a small PCB, but we have to stop it flickering when the components are placed close together or we can't progress to the next stages. Can't just leave it spread out on the breadboard. So I'm looking for suggestions on how to stop the flickering.

Schematic corrected.

What are you using for your +12V source? Could it have a 50 Hz ripple?

There are a couple of different models of 2N2222, with different pinouts. See this Wikipedia article. Make sure you are connecting yours the right way.

It's probably oscillating somehow -- don't have a photo of your setup. Try adding 47k from the output drain to the base of the NPN. That will give positive feedback and some hysteresis. Also remove the 1k in the gate

It is not our job to read your mind or solve your problem with insufficient information. Pictures would help. (Answering questions would help. What is your power source?) You are probably unintentionally creating an oscillator. Try adding a small coil (some inductance 1uH) or small capacitors (100pF) at different places in your circuit. Report back with anything that works, and we'll hopefully be able to take you further.
